# Why it says "java.sql.SQLException: invalid column name"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle10g

I'm trying to get results from DB

```
        String strCommand = "select TO_CHAR (realdate, 'YYYYMMDD'), PURCHASE_PRICE, SELLING_PRICE from CURRENCY_VI where RATE_NAME='EUR'";

        cs.setQueryTimeout(m_nTimeout);

        ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery(strCommand);

        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.println("!!!\n\nDATE = " + rs.getString("realdate") + " PURCHASE_PRICE = " + rs.getString("PURCHASE_PRICE") + " SELLING_PRICE = " + rs.getString("SELLING_PRICE"));
        }
```

It says that `rs.getString("realdate")` - "*java.sql.SQLException: invalid column name*", why?

Without `rs.getString("realdate")` everything works fine.

Actually, table has this column

```
  CREATE TABLE "GPB"."CURRENCY_VI" 
   (           "REALDATE" DATE, 
                "PURCHASE_PRICE" FLOAT(126), 
                "SELLING_PRICE " FLOAT(126), 
                "RATE_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   )
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are not selecting `realdate`. You are selecting `TO_CHAR (realdate, 'YYYYMMDD')`, and that column gets that name. You could do something like this:

```
TO_CHAR (realdate, 'YYYYMMDD') as myrealdate
```

and select that. (with `` `rs.getString("myrealdate") `` ofcourse, not with `realdate`)

Answer (score 4):

There is no column `realdate` in your `SELECT` clause. You select `TO_CHAR (realdate, 'YYYYMMDD')`, which is *not* the same thing. You might want to try using `getString("TO_CHAR (realdate, 'YYYYMMDD')")` and if that doesn't work use `AS` to give that column a name:

```
select TO_CHAR (realdate, 'YYYYMMDD') AS realdate, PURCHASE_PRICE, SELLING_PRICE from CURRENCY_VI where RATE_NAME='EUR'
```

Alternatively you can use the column-index based selection: `rs.getString(1)` (note that the index in JDBC is always 1-based).

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting the function `TO_CHAR (realdate, 'YYYYMMDD')` on the `REALDATE` field, not the field itself. Add an alias to it and use that alias to retrieve the result.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (realdate, 'YYYYMMDD') as realdate_str, ....

rs.getString("realdate_str");
```

Answer (score 0):

"realdate" is not in ur select query
make ur query like this

```
String strCommand = "select REALDATE, PURCHASE_PRICE, SELLING_PRICE from CURRENCY_VI where RATE_NAME='EUR'";
```